# How to resolve totally app freeze after DocuSign login

Tags: ios, swift, docusignapi

My app totally freeze after successful login to DocuSign

Here my code:

```
@IBAction private func signDocument(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let hostURL = URL(string: Environment.current.docuSignHost) else { return }
        isLoading = true
        DSMManager.login(withEmail: Environment.current.docuSignUserID,
                         password: Environment.current.docuSignPass,
                         integratorKey: Environment.current.docuSignIntegratorKey,
                         host: hostURL) { [weak self] info, error in
            self?.isLoading = false
            if let error = error {
                self?.error = error
            } else {
                self?.showDocuSign(info: info)
            }
        }
    }
    
// MARK: - Helpers
    
private func showDocuSign(info: DSMAccountInfo?) {
    guard let info = info else { return }
    envelopManager.perform(with: info, presentingController: self)
}

final class EnvelopeManager {
        
        private let envelopesManager = DSMEnvelopesManager()
        private let templateManager = DSMTemplatesManager()
        
        // MARK: - Lifecycle
        
        func sync() {
            envelopesManager.syncEnvelopes()
        }
        
        func perform(with config: DSMAccountInfo, presentingController: UIViewController) {
            guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: R.file.tgkCapitalPortfolioBAgreementPdf.name, ofType: "pdf") else { return }
            
            let envelopDefinition = DSMEnvelopeDefinition()
            envelopDefinition.envelopeName = "Some name"
            envelopDefinition.emailSubject = "Please Sign Envelope on Document"
            envelopDefinition.emailBlurb = "Hello, Please sign my Envelope"
            
            let builder = DSMDocumentBuilder()
            builder.addDocumentId("1")
            builder.addName(R.file.tgkCapitalPortfolioBAgreementPdf.name)
            builder.addFilePath(Bundle.main.path(forResource: R.file.tgkCapitalPortfolioBAgreementPdf.name,
                                                 ofType: "pdf")!)
            let document = builder.build()
            
            envelopDefinition.documents = [document]
            
            let signHere = DSMSignHere()
            signHere.documentId = document.documentId
            signHere.pageNumber = 1
            signHere.recipientId = "1"
            signHere.frame = .init(originX: 100,
                                   originY: 100,
                                   width: 100,
                                   height: 100,
                                   originYOffsetApplied: 50)
            signHere.tabId = "1"
            
            let tabs = DSMTabs()
            tabs.signHereTabs = [signHere]
            
            let signer = DSMSigner()
            signer.email = config.email
            signer.name = config.userName
            signer.userId = config.userId
            signer.clientUserId = config.userId
            signer.routingOrder = 1
            signer.recipientId = "1"
            signer.tabs = tabs
            
            let signers: [DSMSigner] = [signer]
            
            let recipients = DSMRecipients()
            recipients.signers = signers
            
            envelopDefinition.recipients = recipients
            envelopDefinition.status = "created"
            
            envelopesManager.composeEnvelope(with: envelopDefinition, signingMode: .offline) { [weak self] envelopID, error in
                if let envelopID = envelopID {
                    print(envelopID)
                    self?.presentSigning(presenter: presentingController,
                                         envelopeID: envelopID)
                } else {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        
        private func presentSigning(presenter: UIViewController, envelopeID: String) {
            envelopesManager.resumeSigningEnvelope(withPresenting: presenter,
                                                   envelopeId: envelopeID) { (viewController, error) in
                if let viewController = viewController {
                    print(viewController)
                }

                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

All closures have a success status but the app freezes and any DocuSign view controllers are not showing.
But if in the second attempt I add the calling the `logout` before login - all works as expected

```
@IBAction private func signDocument(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let hostURL = URL(string: Environment.current.docuSignHost) else { return }
        isLoading = true
        DSMManager.logout()
        DSMManager.login(withEmail: Environment.current.docuSignUserID,
                         password: Environment.current.docuSignPass,
                         integratorKey: Environment.current.docuSignIntegratorKey,
                         host: hostURL) { [weak self] info, error in
            self?.isLoading = false
            if let error = error {
                self?.error = error
            } else {
                self?.showDocuSign(info: info)
            }
        }
    }
```

How to resolve this issue? How to make that my app will not freeze after any successful login?

### Edit1

I have figured out that the total app freeze is occurring by the first app install. When I open an app that was already installed and I many times opened it earlier and go to DocuSign flow, call `logout` and finally call `login`- all works as expected - I don't have any app freeze. But if I don't call the `logout` method in this chain then my app freezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was consistent in that `DSMManager.setup()` called earlier than `applicationDidLaunch`. After I moved it to `applicationDidLaunch` the problem was resolved

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting the solution @igdev.

Yes, correct sequence to perform SDK setup is during `applicationDidLaunch` or afterwards, say during `viewDidLoad()` of any of the viewControllers (lazy sdk setup & initialization). As long as `setup()` is done prior to any of the sdk-calls such as `login(withAccessToken:...)` or `cacheEnvelope(...)`. DocuSign SDK `setup()` establishes the core data and other essential components required for its functionality.

Typical sequence of calls made with DocuSign SDK.

1. Application Launch
2. Initialize DocuSign SDK with `DocuSignSDK setup()`
3. Login with `DocuSignSDK login(with...)`. Login could be skipped if a prior SDK session is already established, for e.g. when getting signatures in offline-envelopes using downloaded templates.
4. Accessing `TemplatesManager` or `EnvelopesManager` functionality [Download templates, Sign Envelopes, Sync offline envelopes, etc] and other tasks such as handling DocuSign-SDK notifications to track events (e.g. `Signing Completed` `Envelope Cached`, etc).
5. Logout, it's not required, if needed can perform `DSMManager.logout()` when client user is logged out.